# Refreshing Tkinter root window for Multiplication Table

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, tkinter

I am new to Python and trying to create a Multiplication Table in Python 3.8 using an array of Labels to hold each Line string. The code works but on subsequent Button clicks, it appends new sets of labels just below the first set, to the Root window instead of first clearing it.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
sizex = 600; sizey = 400; posx  = 0; posy  = 0
root.wm_geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (sizex, sizey, posx, posy))

labels = []  # creates an empty list for your labels
def showTable():
    del labels[:] # delete any previous labels from window --> doesn't work?
    nums = range(10)
    tbl = entry.get()

    for i in nums:  # iterates over your nums
        txt = tbl + ' x ' + str(i + 1) + ' = ' + str(int(tbl) * (i + 1))
        label = Label(root, text = txt, bg = 'cyan')  # set your text and random bgcolor --> how to randomize color?
#       label.place(x = 10, y = 10 + (30 + i))
        label.pack()
        labels.append(label)  # appends the label to the list for further use

entry = Entry(root)
entry.place(x = 50,y = 50) # doesn't place the textbox at given positions?
entry.pack()

btn = Button(root, text = 'Show Table', command = showTable)
btn.place(x = 100, y = 100) # doesn't place the button at given positions?
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Multiplication Table]

I have added comments where i think code is not working. Any help will be most appreciated in rectifying and optimizing this code. Also, is there a way to randomize the background color on each line?

Comment: You could re-use the labels: create the labels beforehand then modify their content by e.g. `label[i]['text] = "({} x {} = {}).format(arg1,arg2,arg3)"`. If you still want to destroy a widget (maybe sub-optimal approach) iterate over each label widget and do `.destroy()`. In addition you could "hide" widgets (made by the `pack` geometry manager) do `label[i].pack_forget()`.

Comment: @Space can you post it as an answer?

Comment: An anwser was already accepted, just a correction: to modify a widget's "attributes" use either `label[i]["text"] = "({} x {} = {})".format(arg1,arg2,arg3)` or `label[i].configure(text="({} x {} = {})".format(arg1,arg2,arg3))`. In addition, I strongly recommend you re-use the labels instead of destroying and recreating them on each iteration.

Comment: @Space you're right about re-using. I agree about it. Can I supplement my answer with a code where lables are re-used?

Comment: of course you can, no need for asking.

Comment: @sifar I supplemented my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just delete the labels from the `label` list. They still exist. You need to use `destroy` method to remove a widget from its container. Also the C-style formatting (%) is almost obsolete today, `str.format` or f-strings are much better.

Also you could place all the labels into a `Frame` object and then destroy only that `Frame`. In this case you will not have to use a collection for the labels. And probably if some values are used only once, it is not necessary to create a variable for them. Of course, it is not the case, when a value is taken from some complicated expressions or you need to clarify its meaning through its name.

Also only one method of packing element can be used for a window. You cannot use one method and then another. I. e. you select `pack`, `grid` or `place` and then use only that selected method. If you want to place the widgets at top center, `pack` does it by default and it is more handy to use than `place`. `pack` has `side` parameter used to select packing direction and `pady` with `padx` parameters used to select outer padding.

And `entry` variable name is not a good approach, because it gives no information about what data would be entered there.

For random color you can use `random.choice` function.

Here is your code with my changes:

```py
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()
sizex = 600;
sizey = 400;
posx  = 0;
posy  = 0
root.wm_geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(sizex, sizey, posx, posy))
main_outer_pady = 4
bg_colors = 'red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green', 'gray'

labels = []  # creates an empty list for your labels
def showTable():
    for l in labels:
        l.destroy()
    labels.clear()

    entered_num = num_to_multiply_entry.get()
    for i in range(10):  # iterates over your nums
        txt = f'{entered_num} x {str(i + 1)} = {int(entered_num) * (i + 1)}'
        # Here we randomize background color. We can
        # randomize foreground color with the same way.
        label = Label(root, text=txt, bg=random.choice(bg_colors))

        label.pack(pady=main_outer_pady)
        labels.append(label)  # appends the label to the list for further use

num_to_multiply_entry = Entry(root)
num_to_multiply_entry.pack(pady=main_outer_pady)

btn = Button(root, text='Show Table', command=showTable)
btn.pack(pady=main_outer_pady)

root.mainloop()
```

Edits:

Labels reusing example:

```py
from tkinter import *
from random import choice


sizex = 600
sizey = 400
posx = 0
posy = 0
main_outer_pady = 4
bg_colors = 'red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green', 'gray'
labels = []

def update_table():
    entered_num = num_to_multiply_entry.get()
    # Iterates over your nums.
    for i in range(1, 11):
        txt = f'{entered_num} x {i} = {int(entered_num) * i}'
        # Here we randomize background color. We can
        # randomize foreground color with the same way.
        labels[i-1].configure(text=txt, bg=choice(bg_colors))

root = Tk()
root.wm_geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(sizex, sizey, posx, posy))

num_to_multiply_entry = Entry(root)
num_to_multiply_entry.pack(pady=main_outer_pady)
make_table_btn = Button(root, text='Show Table', command=update_table)
make_table_btn.pack(pady=main_outer_pady)

for i in range(10):
    labels.append(Label(root))
    labels[-1].pack(pady=main_outer_pady)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks @Splitter. This works and thanks once again for the clear explanation to my other queries.

Comment: I think you are using a hard way to achieve that, Destroy those widgets, clear the list, pack them again, append them to the list.....

Comment: @Kevin Mayo the approach with destroying is not mine. I wanted to not change the original code entirely when was writing it. By the way, now I write another code with widgets re-using. I agree that destroying is not a good way.

Answer (score 3):

`del labels[:]` could work normally, but it wouldn't update the widgets of your window.
For efficiency, I recommend you put them on your window firstly, then just update the text and the "bg".

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
sizex = 600;
sizey = 400;
posx = 0;
posy = 0
root.wm_geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (sizex, sizey, posx, posy))

def showTable():
    tbl = entry.get()
    # change the text and "bg" instead of create them again.
    for i, widget in enumerate(labels):
        txt = tbl + ' x ' + str(i + 1) + ' = ' + str(int(tbl) * (i + 1))
        widget.config(text=txt)
        widget.config(bg='cyan')

entry = Entry(root)
entry.place(x=50, y=50)  # doesn't place the textbox at given positions?
entry.pack()

btn = Button(root, text='Show Table', command=showTable)
btn.place(x=100, y=100)  # doesn't place the button at given positions?
btn.pack()

nums = range(10)

# save them in a list, and use pack layout manager to put them on your window.
labels = [label.pack() or label for i in nums for label in [Label(root)]]

root.mainloop()
```